# Subscribe a topic with mosquitto and node-red?

Tags: mosquitto, node-red

I am using mosquitto along with node-red to subscribe to a concrete topic, I know that the mosquitto syntax should be like below, where *AppEUI* is a string, *DevEUI* too, being in my case something akin to *DevEUI=0000000002010103* and pwd my password

```
mosquitto_sub -h staging.thethingsnetwork.org -t 'AppEUI/devices/DevEUI/up' -u DevEUI -P 'pwd'
```

I am using the node input mqtt to achieve the same, however when I include the AppEUI as part of the topic to subscribe to, mosquitto broker crashes and it restarted... So I was wondering if I am doing something wrong, because if I make use of the wildcard `+` then it seems to work fine.

May someone enlight me with this? I have attached a pic of my current flow
[image]
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: this a foto of the situation when mqtt restarts[image]

Comment: Do you mean the mosquitto broker crashes or node-red crashes? It's not clear what you mean. Please include some log data that shows the problem

Comment: @hardlib mosquitto broker crashes, I will edit that and add some log

Comment: Screenshots for logs really are not that helpful, in lining the log would be a lot more useful

Comment: You need to be more specific about what it is that seems to trigger the mosquitto crash. What did you do (or what happened) immediately before 14:39:46?

Your screenshot shows you editing an inject node to a topic starting with a +, not sure what that would do, is that relevant?

Also, have you tried connecting your app to a different mqtt broker, e.g. the public test broker on messagesight.demos.ibm.com?